# add CSS animation to h1 on clicking a button using JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

so... I have a h1 and a button. I want to add animation which i created using `CSS` to the h1 on clicking the button using `JQuery`.

When you click the button, the animation should add more content to `h1`.
I want it to start when I click the button but it starts as soon as I load the `HTML`.

As I am new to this skill, I am unable to understand other complex answers. Please help me out.

here's the `HTML`:

```html
<div class="container-fluid center" id="mainPage">
    <div id="heading" class="row">
        <h1 id="wishH1">NAME!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid center" id="gift">
    <button type="button" id="giftButton">
        <img id="giftImg" src="gift.png">
    </button>
</div>
```

here's the CSS:

```css
@keyframes wish {
  25% {
    content: : "hi ";
  }
  50% {
    content: : "hello ";
  }
  75% {
    content: "hola ";
  }
}

#wishH1::before {
  content: "hey there ";
  animation: wish 20s linear infinite;
}
```

here's the `JQuery`:

different comments show different things I've tried to do after removing the animation part from `CSS` but they don't even start the animation...

```js
$('#giftButton').click(function() {
  $("#gift").fadeOut(1500);
  /*$("#wishH1").css("animation",wish);
    $("#wishH1").css("animation-duration",6s);
    $("#wishH1").css("animation-timing-function",linear);
    $("#wishH1").css("animation-iteration-count",infinite);*/
  /*$("#wishH1").animate({animation: "wish 6s linear infinite"});*/
  /*("#wishH1").css("animation-play-state","running");*/
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#gift").fadeIn(1500);
  }, 20000);
});
```

the `h1` changes like:

```
hey there NAME!

hi NAME!

hello NAME!

hola NAME!
```

now, this starts playing the animation as soon as I start the html but I want it to play after I click the button.

I have some other content in `html` and `css` but to make it short, I removed the irrelevant stuff.
Please let me know where and what should I add or remove in `JQuery` or remove from `CSS` to get the desired output. Thank you!

P.S. as this is my first question, it may not be described properly. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Instead of CSS  content property you can use js  method innerHTML or jquery   .text() or .html()

Comment: chech this [https://jsfiddle.net/hrxpjes6/](https://jsfiddle.net/hrxpjes6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the animation after the click but you can't select pseudo elements (the `::before` part) in jQuery, because they are not part of DOM. But you can add a specific class (`animation-start`) to the parent element and control its pseudo elements in CSS.

```js
$('#giftButton').click(function() {
  $("#gift").fadeOut(1500);
  $('#wishH1').addClass('animation-start');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#gift").fadeIn(1500);
  }, 20000);
});
```

```css
@keyframes wish {
  25% {
    content: "hi ";
  }
  50% {
    content: "hello ";
  }
  75% {
    content: "hola ";
  }
}

#wishH1::before {
  content: "hey there ";
}

#wishH1.animation-start::before {
  animation: wish 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid center" id="mainPage">
  <div id="heading" class="row">
    <h1 id="wishH1">NAME!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid center" id="gift">
  <button type="button" id="giftButton">
        <img id="giftImg" src="gift.png">
    </button>
</div>
```

There were also extra semicolons in your CSS here that may caused you some trouble.

```
@keyframes wish{
25%{
    content:: /* here */ "hi "; 
}
50%{
    content:: /* here */ "hello "; 
}
75% {
    content: "hola ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the css code you direcly set the animation. you need to add the animation on click.

Something like this:

### css

```css
@keyframes wish{
25%{
    content: "hi ";
}
50%{
    content: "hello ";
}
75% {
    content: "hola ";
}
}
#wishH1::before{
  content: "hey there ";
}

#wishH1.active::before{
  animation: wish 2s linear infinite;
}
```

### js

```js
$('#giftButton').click(function(){
$('#wishH1').addClass('active')
$("#gift").fadeOut(1500);
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#gift").fadeIn(1500);
    $('#wishH1').removeClass('active')
}, 20000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<h1><span id="animate_text"></span> NAME!</h1>
<button type="button" id="giftButton">
      <img id="giftImg" src="gift.png">
    </button>
```

JQUERY CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
  let interval;
  let i = 0;
  let values = ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Hola']

  $('#giftButton').on("click", function () {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      if (i >= values.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
      $('#animate_text').text(values[i]);
      i++
    },
      2000);
  })
```

Comment: @amaan instead of using css use jQuery and html only then I. jQuery u can use .animate() or fade or other methods which will make it much cleaner and easier !

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot directly set the style of a pseudo element through Javascript, you can set a CSS variable on the actual element and this will be picked up by the pseudo element.

So we start by setting --name: none and then in the Javascript (or jquery) set the CSS variable to wish and the animation will start.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('#wishH1').style.setProperty('--name', 'wish');
});
```

```css
@keyframes wish{
25%{
    content: "hi ";
}
50%{
    content: "hello ";
}
75% {
    content: "hola ";
}
}

#wishH1 {
  --name: none;
}
#wishH1::before {
  content: "Hey there ";
  animation: var(--name) 20s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid center" id="mainPage">
    <div id="heading" class="row">
        <h1 id="wishH1">NAME!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid center" id="gift">
    <button type="button" id="giftButton">
        <img id="giftImg" src="gift.png">
    </button>
</div>
```